# Python delineate recursive generator call/yield stack

Tags: python, recursion

I have created the below recursive generator, but am struggling to fully understand the call and yield stacks. Is someone able to offer a bit of insight into what this is actually doing please?

```
lis = [1, 2, 3]

def parts(l=lis):
    print(l)
    if len(l) == 1:
        yield l[0]
    else:
        for p in parts(l[1:]):
            yield p
```

I set a breakpoint on the last line and couldn't follow what was happening each step. I want to yield `[3]` then `[2]` then `[1]` recursively. This is a simplification of a more complex problem, hence, I can't just iterate through the list like usual.

Comment: Since you created that function, what is it supposed to do?

Comment: I want it to reduce the list from `[1, 2, 3]` to `[2, 3]` to `[3]` and then "backtrack" from `[3]` to `[2, 3]` to `[1, 2, 3]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments, it looks like you're looking for something like:

```
lis = [1, 2, 3]
def parts(l=lis):
    yield l
    if len(l) != 1:
        yield from parts(l[1:])
    yield l
```

And then you'd get the results with:

```
for i in parts():
    print(i)
```

The results I get are:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[2, 3]
[3]
[3]
[2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: `if len(l) != 1: yield l` for the last line will remove the duplicate if the "backtrack" needs it like that